# How to get base filename without query portion?

Tags: c#, filepath

Given a <del>file path</del> *URL* such as `http://example.com/video.flv?start=5`, I want to get out `video.flv`.

`Path.GetFileName("http://example.com/video.flv?start=5")` yields `video.flv?start=5`, which is more than I want. I can't find anything relevant in the `Uri` class either. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's not a file path - it's a URL.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's a path to a file on the web.

Comment: @Mark - Path is for filesystem paths.  Uri is for URI's.

Comment: @Mark: Please don't confuse URLs/URIs with file system paths, which is what the `Path` class is about.

Comment: (Note that a URL doesn't have to be backed by a "file" at all.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: When I wrote "file path" I wasn't referring to the `Path` class though, I was referring to a path to a file, whether it lives on the web or on my local machine. Whether it's a real "file" or one that's generated by the server on the fly isn't particularly relevant. If I wrote `file:///C://myfile.txt`, what would that be? Anyway, I understand your point. The format of the string is different; I've updated the question to use the correct terminology.

Comment: @Mark: But your *code* refers to the `Path` class, which simply isn't meant to handle URLs. A URL of "file:///C://myfile.txt" is still a URL, but it refers to a file on the file system. That's fine, but still not the kind of thing that `Path` is meant to handle.

Comment: @JonSkeet: This I can accept :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Various ways, but one option:

```
new Uri("http://example.com/video.flv?start=5").Segments.Last()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Uri.AbsolutePath` I was able to achieve the desired results.

```
Uri t = new Uri("http://example.com/video.flv?start=5");
Console.WriteLine(t.AbsolutePath);
Console.ReadLine();
```

printed `/video.flv`

Comment: I don't want the slash or directories.